# Boolean Cut Flickering

Tags: rendering, modifiers, particles

I came across a tutorial on YouTube on how to make a disintegration effect and have tried to integrate it into my film: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wm4rDDRcbDQ.

However, I've stumbled over a bit of an issue. Most of it works, but I'm seeing a bit of flickering with the boolean modifier as it cuts down the mesh (which is a 3D scan of one of my actors): https://i.stack.imgur.com/IeNHk.jpg

I don't suppose anyone knows how to fix this? It seems to be a problem with the boolean but only on certain parts of the mesh. I've tried recomputing normals and decimating the mesh but to no avail. Any advice would be very much welcomed :S

Comment: the boolean modifier is flaky at times, esp. with unclean meshes (typical for 3d scans). Given, that it doesn't work on a few frames you might look specifically at the position that gets intersected and see if there is any bad mesh topology. You might also try nudge the position of the intersecting mesh, so it skips that bad parts at 24 frames per second it will be very difficult to tell. You might also try the remesh modifier to clean the mesh.

Comment: Coplanar surfaces usually create problems with boolean operations. By looking at the animation you posted, I would suggest not to use booleans at all and render the particle animation separately and combine it with the render of the foreground in the compositor.

Comment: Cheers, thanks for the tips. Will gradually work my way through them to find the solution :D